# Generate pdf file on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, printing

How would I be able to generate a **pdf** file when a button is clicked?

I have a user profile page and when I hit print, it should generate a **pdf** file containing the data of that user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation lists most of your options for pdf libraries

Comment: @house9 I'm new to RoR. Which one is recommendable for beginners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of difference PDF generation ruby libraries but I would recommend [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com).  For example:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
end
```

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised) is an excellent railscast that goes through the basics which should get you on the right track.

Comment: I'm only new to rails. Will this generate the data based on the currently viewed profile page.

Comment: @seed when your users click a button, you will want to send that event to your server and then put code like the above this in a model.  From the model, you can query whatever data you need to and add it to the pdf document.

Comment: is there any way that i could probably do the pdf generation w/o querying?

Comment: Prawn gives you lots of control for generating pdf, but if you want to just do html to pdf, see http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit

Comment: Btw. Can i generate a table on prawn?

Comment: @seed, absolutely. http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Table.html